# Applescript Find & Replace in Text Document from Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, macos, macros, applescript

I'm new to `Applescript` and am trying to create a script that can run through a text document (.html) and find & replace various phrases with a corresponding cell in an Excel document.

I will put placeholders in the text to be replaced as `B_1 (first value to replace), B_2 (second), B_3` etc...

They should be replaced in order using the cells `B1-B9` in the Excel document. The phrases in the Excel document will be changed each time, hence why it has to be dynamic to capture them rather than a standard find & replace script with static values.

I've been following this thread which all makes sense: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7008048?start=0&tstart=0

However, I keep running into compile errors. Here is my current code:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
set colB_data to value of every cell of range "B1:B9" of worksheet 1 of document 1
end tell

tell application "Sublime Text"
tell text of "Users/maxquinn/Desktop/index.html"
repeat with index from 1 to count colB_data
replace ("B_" & index as text) using (item index of colB_data) options {starting at top:true, match words:true}
end repeat
end tell
end tell
```

The first half works fine, but the second half gives me the error `"Expected end of line but found identifier."` and highlights the `'using'` in the `'replace' command (line 8)`.

Does anyone know why this might be, and are there any other glaring errors in the script?

Thanks!

Max

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the future, this question was solved over on the Apple forums here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7618440